# How to output a specific element value to console.log by clicking a specific element

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exWQU.png)

As shown in the picture above, when the first element value is 7,
If I click, I want to output 7 in console.log.

```
var container1 = document.createElement('div')
container1.className = 'container1';
document.body.appendChild(container1);
for(var index = 0;index < 20 ; index++){
   var aa = document.createElement('span')
   aa.innerHTML = card1[index];
   container1.appendChild(aa);
   aa.className = 'card'+index;
   aa.addEventListener('click',clickEvent)
}
function clickEvent(){
   //What code should I use?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how are you?

Try this:

```
function clickEvent(evt){
   console.log(evt.target.innerHTML)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of HTML elements in JavaScript. To complete this you would also need to pass the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) into your clickEvent function. Click events have a [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which is the HTML node that was clicked. The event

```
var container1 = document.createElement('div')
container1.className = 'container1';
document.body.appendChild(container1);
for(var index = 0;index < 20 ; index++){
   var aa = document.createElement('span')
   aa.innerHTML = card1[index];
   container1.appendChild(aa);
   aa.className = 'card'+index;
   aa.addEventListener('click',clickEvent)
}
function clickEvent(event){
   //What code should I use?
   let clickedBox = event.target;
   console.log(clickedBox.textContent);
}
```

As far as I know, this should work like you're intending. I haven't worked with the front-end side of JS lately, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the click event in your function `clickEvent` by doing so:

```
function clickEvent(event){
   console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
```

Capturing the event is done by passing it as an argument while creating your function, do not pass it when you add it to the event listener.

The event is the clicking event, one of its properties is something called target that points to the element that the event `click` has occurred on, from there you can access anything almost on that element, including its value which I assume you meant its text (the number on it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided the **HTML** and **CSS** too then it will be a direct answer to your need but a similar approach can be done using `this` keyword which print `innerHTML` of each `span` tag on click

```js
function paret(reed) {
  console.log(reed.innerHTML)
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span onclick="paret(this)">7</span>
  <span onclick="paret(this)">17</span>
  <span onclick="paret(this)">9</span>
  <span onclick="paret(this)">8</span>
  <span onclick="paret(this)">5</span>
</div>
```